# Is there a more performant way of filtering thata out than NOT IN?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with two columns. One Column is the *Material number* and the other one is the *Language*. 
Some Material numbers have multiple Languages and I would like to only get those that do not have a 'DE' or 'EN' entry. So basically as soon as a material number has a 'DE' or 'EN' in the lang field it should not be displayed.

**This is the Query that I tried using:**

```
select * from table where matnr not in (select matnr from table where lang = "DE" or lang = "EN")
```

However the Data I am trying to analyze has over a million entries which takes really really long.

The weird thing is that I even

```
select top 1 * from table where matnr not in (select matnr from table where lang = "DE" or lang = "EN")
```

seems to take a really long time.

Am I doing something wrong here? Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve the same thing in a way that is more performant?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `not exists` with an index on `(matnr, lang)`:

```
select t.*
from table as t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table as t2
                  where t2.matnr = t.matnr AND
                        t2.lang = "DE"
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table as t2
                  where t2.matnr = t.matnr AND
                        t2.lang = "EN"
                 ) ;
```

Another would use aggregation and `INNER JOIN`:

```
select t.*
from table as t inner join
     (select t2.matnr
      from table as t2
      group by t2.matnr
      having sum(iff(lang in ("DE", "EN"), 1, 0)) = 0
     ) as t2
     on t.matnr = t2.matnr;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems way more performant! I tried the first one and it worked really fast. However I do have one more question. Shouldn't changing "not exists" into "exists" output the other data? Like if there is 1.000.000 rows in "table" and your first query outputs 500.000 material numbers, then changing the query to "exists" should also output 500.000 materials given that there is no null values right?

Comment: @abapme . . . You also need to change the `and` to `or`.

Comment: Oh I see my mistake now! :) Thank you very much for your help, I will be reading more about Exists, they only taught us the Query "Not In" back in School but it seems really useful. I appreaciate your help, it worked in seconds! :)

Comment: @abapme . . . Performance aside, I always recommend `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery over `NOT IN`, because `NOT EXISTS` handles `NULL` values more intuitively.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there a performance related reason for using 2 `not exists` subqueries instead of 1 with `where t2.lang in ('DE', 'EN)`? Or is that an Ms Access thing?

Comment: @Gandalf . . . Probably that is okay.  However, I'm more confident that MS Access will optimize the two subqueries correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `left join` coupled with a `where is null` clause, e.g.:

```
select top 1 t1.*
from 
    table t1 left join 
    (
        select distinct t2.matnr
        from table t2 where t2.lang = 'DE' or t2.lang = 'EN'
    ) 
    on t1.matnr = t2.matnr
where 
    t2.matnr is null
```